# How do I add multiple objects into one JSON file, and then list everything in that file? [JSON, JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

Here is my code:

```
    const addReaction = {
    reaction: `${args[0]}`,
    webhook: `${args[1]}`,
    }

    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(addReaction);

    fs.appendFileSync('./reactions.json', jsonString, err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Success!");
    }
    });
```

Once the command is ran, the addReaction var should be put into the reactions.json file, and then it can be ran again, adding the addReaction var again along with different user input. Then with a different command, I can read the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just append to a JSON string, you will get invalid JSON. You should parse the JSON, modify the data and then JSONify it again.

**Suggestion**

```
// reactions.json
[
  {"reaction": "blah", "webhook": "bleh"} 
]

// add-reaction.js

const addReaction = {
  reaction: `${args[0]}`,
  webhook: `${args[1]}`,
}
const rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./add-reactions.json');
const reactions = JSON.parse(rawdata);
reactions.push(addReaction);
fs.writeFileSync( './add-reactions.json', JSON.stringify(reactions), fileOptions );
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: `ReferenceError: fileOptions is not defined`

Comment: @Johonny You need to define that yourself. i can't tell what kind of file access you need, please read [its documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options). For the most basic solution, you can pass in 'utf-8'

Comment: Would I replace fileOptions with "utf8"?

Comment: Can you help me further with this?

Comment: Isn't that exactly what my comment said? Did you read the docs, did you try anything? Any error messages?